# Executing command in shell script which contain "-"(Hyphen)

Tags: shell

I want execute below command in shell script

```
CMD="/abc/def/ghi command1 command2 -p $VARIABLE --command3 true"
```

while executing this `exec $CMD` hyphen replacing with single quotes pasting debug output

```
+ exec '/abc/def/ghi command1 command2 ' 'p VALUE ' '' 'command3 true'
```

How to deal with it ?

Comment: Did you somehow manage to set `$IFS` to `-`?

Answer (score 0):

Read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#050)

You want to use an array to store the command

```
cmd=(/abc/def/ghi command1 command2 -p "$variable" --command3 true)
exec "${cmd[@]}"
```

Or a function, but I'm not sure how to `exec` a function, unless you put it in the function

```
cmd() { exec /abc/def/ghi command1 command2 -p "$variable" --command3 true; }
cmd
```

Don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: leave those reserved for the shell.